# What projection matrix does SceneKit use for directional light shadows?

Tags: scenekit, shadow-mapping, directional-light

I'm trying to prevent shadow swimming when moving the directional light around to cover only the visible part of my scene.  Despite rounding the translation components in light space, they swimming artifacts are still there.

I even tried pointing the light directly down (with a scale of 2 and shadow map size of 32) and translated the directional light along the world x-axis by -1 and +1.  The shadows still changed. I can only assume they aren't using normal orthographic projection. The shadows seem to move more when near the edge too.

Has anyone had luck preventing shadow swimming in SceneKit, or knows what projection matrix is being used for the directional light shadows?